# Rails Active Record where object has an Attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, where-clause

I'm trying to do something like...

```
self.where(active: true, latitude: !nil)
```

this doesn't work.  I basically need something that queries for objects who HAVE a latitude property which has a value.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this also works

```
self.where("active = ? AND latitude IS NOT ?", true, nil)
```

OR

Rails 4 way

```
self.where(active: true).where().not(latitude: nil)
```